# vim close all buffers but one

Tags: vim, buffer

How can I close all buffers but one in vim?  I'm looking for an `:only` command, but for buffers.  I've had trouble finding this using `:help` and `:helpgrep`, does anyone know if this exists?  I know you can close multiple buffers with `:bd some# other# etc..`, but that's a bit slow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a plugin that will do what you want:

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1071

Comment: hmm, that looks alright, but doesn't seem to load with [vim-unbundle](https://github.com/sunaku/vim-unbundle), so I need to `:source` it manually.  Do you know why?

Comment: I've never used unbundle so I'm not sure. But from what I read in the link you provided, unbundle looks for bundle directories. BufOnly is just a single .vim file. So `:source` it or just download it to your plugins directory.

Answer (score 3):

Try out `:%bd|e#` which says "delete all buffers, then open the last one for editing".

Beyond the scope of this Q/A, here's a block I still use year's later:

```
" close all but current buffer
command! BufOnly silent! execute "%bd|e#|bd#"
nnoremap <space>O :BufOnly<cr>

" close all but current window (in a single tab, aka close all other splits)
nnoremap <space>o :only<cr>
```